# gdb + nasm debug info not being created

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm

I am trying to debug a small .asm file that I wrote in Ubuntu.  I am however running into an issue where my symbol table is not being loaded and was looking for some help.

I am compiling my program as follows.

```
nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf bs.asm
gcc -m32 -g bs.o -o bs
```

which produces the executable bs when I run

```
gdb bs
```

I get a message that says no debugging symbols and when I try to set a break point by

```
b main
```

it says function not defined even though its in the file and I can run it using ./bs

I read a couple posts that suggested adding the -F dwarf when assembling but that didn't help if anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciated your input.

Comment: I moved your answer to a proper answer, so the question will no longer look open.

Comment: I've solved a similar problem by removing the `-s` flag from the linker command which was there for some reason.

Answer (score 14):

Assemble your file with the following commands :-

`nasm -f elf -F dwarf -g file.asm`
`ld -m elf_i386 -o file file.o`

and then use gdb,

Comment: This is really helpful! Also it looks like the order of parameters matters.

Answer (score 5):

*cpowel2 solved his own problem:*

SOLVED: Just in case anyone else was having the same issue (it seems like there are a ton of posts on the net) I was able to resolve the issue by changing the section .txt portion of my file to section .text and gdb recognized it right away.

Comment: As someone who had been strugging with this problem for like a day now, I had a similiar problem, turns out that if you have 'segment .text:" , it wont work, you need to make sure your segment lines do not have colons after them!!!

Answer (score 0):

SECTION .text

; in nasm - a text section has to be in lower case for gdb to pick it up.