# Nasm Dwarf Error Bad Offset

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, nasm, dwarf

I have a simple Hello World program for Windows in pure x86 assembly code that I have compiled and linked with *nasm* and *ld*. The problem I am running into is that I can't get *DWARF* debugging to work. I am using *gdb* from Mingw64 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1). This same problem happens if I use *gcc* to link instead of ld. But, the program builds fine, and if I use *STABS* debugging, then everything is fine and dandy.

EDIT: Oops, I completely forgot to give the error that *gdb* shows.

```
...Dwarf Error: bad offset (0x407000) in compilation unit header (offset 0x0 
+ 6) [in module C:\Projects\AsmProjects\HelloWorldWin32\bin\x86\hello32.exe]
(no debugging symbols found)...done
```

The versions of each program are:

```
gdb 7.10.1  
nasm 2.12.02  
ld 2.25  
gcc 6.2.0
```

These are the flags I'm sending to nasm: `-f elf32 -Fdwarf -g`

These are the flags for gcc link: `-o $(BDIR)/x86/$@.exe $^ -L$(Mingw64-x86libs) -lkernel32 -luser32`

And these are from ld link:

```
-mi386pe -o $(BDIR)/x86/$@.exe $^ -L$(Mingw64-x86libs) -lkernel32 -luser32
```

I have a pretty big makefile, so I'm trying to give the least information that is absolutely neccessary.

Here is the source code for the program:

```
global  _main
extern  _GetStdHandle@4
extern  _WriteFile@20
extern  _ExitProcess@4

section .text
_main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp

    ; GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    push    esp
    push    message_end
    push    message
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    push    0
    call    _ExitProcess@4

section .data
message         db      'Hello, World',10
message_end     equ     $ - message
```

Comment: STABS and DWARF debug symbols have a broad overlap. For basic debugging, either should work fine.  Why do you want to use DWARF debugging?

Comment: I don't care particularly which one I use, but I do want to know why DWARF doesn't work, when, as far as I can tell, it should work just fine.

Comment: Can you run dwarfdump on the executable?

Comment: Does dwarfdump come with Mingw64? I'm googleing it, and I can't really find anything. So far I've seen that I can get the sources, but good luck building it on Windows.

Comment: My experience is that DWARF info is not generated correctly by nasm. `readelf` complains when you try to read the DWARF sections.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a proper answer but was too long for the comment section.

I compiled on Ubuntu and then ran `dwarfdump`

It gave an error that may be related to the offset error.

```
dwarfdump ERROR:  dwarf_get_globals:  DW_DLE_PUBNAMES_VERSION_ERROR (123)
```

From a [similar](https://reviews.llvm.org/D1454) error on LLVM, I conclude that the dwarf version information is possibly corrupt or unsupported.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442747/gdb-nasm-debug-info-not-being-created) indicates that the dwarf information is sensitive to the proper section names.  The example appears to have the section names right however.

Have you tried a 64-bit version?  Perhaps a clue will appear.

This program appears to work fine Ubuntu.  Can you try it on Mingw64?

```
section     .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:                                         ;tell linker entry point

    mov     edx,len                             ;message length
    mov     ecx,msg                             ;message to write
    mov     ebx,1                               ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     eax,4                               ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80                                ;call kernel

    mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80                                ;call kernel

section     .data

msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa                 ;our dear string
len     equ $ - msg                             ;length of our dear string
```

Comment: No, it won't work because the code is not compatible with Windows. Well, I'll just go ahead and try it though because why not. Also, I have tried this with an x64 version as well, and it does the same thing as the x86 version.

Comment: Surprisingly, it does build without error, but it has the exact same issue as my Windows version of the code, and when I run it, it crashes with a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Best guess is that particular version of nasm has a bug with the dwarf encoding.  The example worked fine on Ubuntu under gdb.

Comment: Well, I did go try a couple older versions of nasm, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you write any program that actually works with the -Fdwarf?  I would think the dwarf creation would all be bundled inside nasm but maybe it has a library dependency

Comment: Do you, or anybody have a copy of Windows that you could try my project build with? I can send you all the files. The size of all files is about 67Kb.

Comment: Well, my program runs just fine, and everything goes as expected. The only problem is when trying to use DWARF debugging. Note I can still run the program with gdb with DWARF but debugging doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I run OS X and Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123483/discussion-between-matthew-fisher-and-seanramey).

Comment: Upvoted because this is a helpful answer at the very least.